# Get the value of text area with query inside a popUp

Tags: jquery, ajax

Through a click on a button i'm loading an ajax popUp whith the following form-code:

```
 <div id="kom_input">
<form id="mb_kom" action="#">
    <textarea name="kommentar" id="mb_nkommentar" class="mb_overlay_textbox" placeholder="Schreibe einen Kommentar" style="width:352px"></textarea>
    <br><input type="hidden" name="likeid" value="10" id="hidelike"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Senden" class="button" id="btn_nk_kommentar">
</form>
```

If you click on the "sender"-button i'v this jquery-code:

```
 $('body').on('click', '#btn_nk_kommentar', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var like    = $('#hidelike').val();
        var ko      = $('#mb_nkommentar').val();
        $("#kom_input").html( "Danke für ihren Kommentar." );
        alert("h"+like+ko+test);
    })
```

The value for like is working, the one from ko doesn't. Whats wrong!

thanks for any help.

regards
thomas

Comment: sorry, test was a test i tried an forget to remove before copy to stack overflow. pls ignore it

Comment: ..another strange thing i just mentioned. if i click twice to submit, after the second click, there shows me the value.

Comment: maybe, the moment you clicked, the textarea is empty?

Comment: also make sure, you do not have multiple ids

Answer (score 1):

For a textarea use `$('#mb_nkommentar').text()` or `$('#mb_nkommentar').html()`

If that doesn't work, the data isn't in the field yet and you need to populate the data into the textarea *before* the `$.on('click')` fires. Try moving the `$.on('click')` into the success part of the `$.ajax()`. (Apply the handler after the data is populated.)

Answer (score 0):

`var like    = $('#mb_nkommentar').val();`

**Update this to**

`var like = $('#mb_nkommentar').text();`

make sure text area have some value